# How do I save the value of "ons-select" into a variable for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I'm trying to make a code in Onsen Ui whichsaves the date in a variable, and displays the value selected as an alert in JavaScript. Here's a snippet of my code so far:

```js
function exfunction() {
  var MONTH = document.getElementById("Month");
  alert(selectedItem);
}
```

```html
<ons-select id="Month" onchange="editSelects()" v-model="selectedItem">
    <option value="material">January</option>
    <option value="material">Febuary</option>
    <option value="material">March</option>
    <option value="material">April</option>
    <option value="material">May</option>
    <option value="material">June</option>
    <option value="material">July</option>
    <option value="material">August</option>
    <option value="material">September</option>
    <option value="material">October</option>
    <option value="material">November</option>
    <option value="material">December</option>
</ons-select>
```

So I need help on storing the value of the selected item in the ONS-SELECT in a variable to use in JavaScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried- `alert( MONTH.options[MONTH.selectedIndex].value )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `options` property on the `ons-select` element to get a node list of all the options, and then use `selectedIndex` property to get the index of the currently selected option.

```
function editSelects() {
  const selectTag = document.getElementById("Month");
  const months = selectTag.options;
  var selectedMonth = months[selectTag.selectedIndex].value;
  alert( selectedMonth )
}

<ons-select id="Month" onchange="editSelects()" v-model="selectedItem">
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</ons-select>
```

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion, but every time I try to execute this code, the console gives two errors: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null' and 'Uncaught ReferenceError: editSelects is not defined'. What do these errors mean, and how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: @VedTiwari, I have updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: Quick side note: I got no error messages, but the alert keeps saying: "material" sorry I wasn't able to address the problem earlier as I was not around my computer at the time.

Comment: That's because the value for all options is the same = `material`. Change values to the corresponding months as I did on my answer. If you still have error message, please let me know the message.